# Roundoff Limited Error for NLopt AUGLAG - How do I get reasonable values when this error happens and why does it happen?

Tags: python, nlopt

I am using NLopt AUGLAG with COBYLA as the local minimizer function. Why am I getting Roundoff Limited Error? How do I fix this error?

Here are the things I've tried:
Removing all constraints, but it still returned the RoundoffLimited Error. Looking at the value of optimizers and the objective value before it errored, but the objective function value was infinity for the minimization problem. I've also played around with the relative tolerance, but still, no changes.

Because I'm using AUGLAG, I don't think there is a need to define the gradient since the algorithm is gradient-free. Here is the general structure of my code:

```
# setting global variables to keep track of optimizers in case or error
previous_args = None
current_args = None

def myfunc(x, grad):
  global previous_args
  global current_args

  previous_args = current_args
  current_args = x

  occ = 0.5/x
  return sqrt(np.sum((target - occ)**2)/len(x))

def myconstraint(x, grad, a, b):
    return b - np.sum(x*a)
```

```
No = number of optimization variables I have
opt = nlopt.opt(nlopt.AUGLAG, No)

# Set local optimizer for AUGLAG
local_opt = nlopt.opt(nlopt.LN_COBYLA,No)
opt.set_local_optimizer(local_opt)

# Lower bounds for the variables
opt.set_lower_bounds(np.zeros((No)))

# Set objective fn
opt.set_min_objective(myfunc)

# Add constraints, tot_rev is a number
opt.add_inequality_constraint(lambda x,grad: myconstraint(x,grad,2/x,tot_rev), 1e-8)

try:
    x = opt.optimize(np.ones((No)))
except nlopt.RoundoffLimited:
    x = previous_args

# The exact error I get on x = opt.optimize is
# RoundoffLimited: NLopt roundoff-limited if I don't include the exception

# Set relative tolerance on optimization parameters
opt.set_xtol_rel(1e-3)
```